# Ng-show not working for form validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-show

I am trying to use ng-show but for some weird reason it is not appearing on.
When user clicks on first name it should convert from untouched to touched,which it is.But still error code is not appearing.

```
<form role="form" novalidate>
        <h2>Please Sign Up</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fname" ng-model="registerViewModel.first_name" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1" required="" />
          <div ng-show="form.fname.$touched">
            <div ng-show="form.fname.$error.required">Tell us your name</div>
          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="registerViewModel.last_name" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="registerViewModel.email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="email" tabindex="4">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="registerViewModel.password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="registerViewModel.confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                 By clicking <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="button" ng-click="adminRegister.registrationRequest()" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't have name. You should define it like this:

```
<form role="form" name="myname" novalidate>
```

And then refer to it with it's name `myname.fname...`